# Why are declaring leap value as false after defining function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started learning Python and came across this code:This is leap year program.
Why are we defining `leap = False` .The output will be true or false.

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Comment: good for you! see? you just started, and you already found an error in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't  need to define `leap=False` since it is not being used in the code, so you can just remove it and do.

```
def is_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

A bad way to write this and use `leap` will be

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = year % 4 == 0 and (year % 400 == 0 or year % 100 != 0)
    return leap

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `leap` variable in this function isn't even used, and as you assumed, that line is just redundant, and can (should!) be removed.